# How to build a Criteria Query to get all objects that contains certain specifict objects in list

Tags: java, spring, criteria, specifications, criteria-api

I have 2 Classes, One father that have many children, like this:

```
Class Person {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "person_tag",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", 
            referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", 
            referencedColumnName = "id")})    
    List<Tag> tags;

}


Class Tag {

    Long id

}
```

I need to build a Criteria Query to find all persons that have the tags that match with a list of Tag Ids

Im saving this relation in a new table with 2 columns:
person_id
tag_id

I implemented the following solution:

```
  private Specification<Person> generatePersonIdsSpecification(List<Long> ids) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Subquery<Person> sq = query.subquery(Person.class);
            Root<Person> person = sq.from(Person.class);
            ListJoin<Person, Tag> tagJoin = person.joinList("tags");
            sq.select(person).distinct(true).where(tagJoin.get("id").in(ids));
            return cb.in(root).value(sq);
        };
    }
```

But i get:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested attribute was not a list
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.joinList(AbstractFromImpl.java:497) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.joinList(AbstractFromImpl.java:484) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]

Comment: Did you try anything? like select * from person join tag on tag.id = person.tag_id where tag.id in (???) .  Because this two classes have to be in relationship and should face the JPA and Hibernate requirements for entities.

Comment: thank you. I dont' think this "person.tag_id" will work since person have "tags" list. And i prefer do this with a criteria query

Comment: For us to be able to help you, you need to specify your entities structure in the database

Answer (score 0):

Such a query can be built as follows:

```
List<Long> someTagIds ...

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);

Root<Person> person = query.from(Person.class);
ListJoin<Person, Tag> tagJoin = person.joinList("tags");

query.select(person).distinct(true)
     .where(tagJoin.get("id").in(someTagIds));
List<Person> result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried implement that but i get an exception:


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested attribute was not a list, which is not true

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So instead of search for all tags together, i just loop into ids and generate a different specification for each id:

```
private Specification<Person> generateByTagIdSpecification(Long id) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Subquery<Person> sq = query.subquery(Person.class);
            Root<Person> person = sq.from(Person.class);
            Join<Person, Tag> join = person.join("tags");
            sq.select(person).distinct(true).where(cb.equal(join.get("id"), id));
            return cb.in(root).value(sq);
        };
    }
```